# 'Trust this add-in' doesn't work. Excel addin installation flow is broken for all Excel addins

Tags: facebook, office-js

I am following the installation flow as shown in the following webpage. But I was stuck at step 2:

> To finish installing, click 'Trust this Add-in' on the add-in panel.

[image: Screen shot]

I clicked 'Trust this Add-in', but nothing happens. The addin was not loaded. This is breaking our product upsell.

link to the installation page.

https://store.office.com/addinstemplateinstallpage.aspx?rs=en-US&assetid=WA104380711

My Excel version: Microsoft Excel for Mac, version 15.38 (170902)

Comment: I've removed "Please FIX this issue ASAP" from your post. Quite aside from the inappropriate shouting, we're not Facebook - the readership you're addressing are mostly volunteers who are here to help in their spare time. Facebook employees may also read it, but remember you are not addressing them on their own.

Comment: He is just taking Facebook add-in as an example. It seems reproing for any add-ins for him. It feels likes a bug in Microsoft platform.